# IsNull and nullable types in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert the following line of SQL to LINQ code :

```
AND IsNull(Deleted,0) = 0
```

I have tried by doing this :

```
&& Deleted != null ? Deleted : false
```

And this :

```
&& (bool)Deleted != null ? (bool)Deleted : false
```

The first attempt gave me an error as Deleted is a nullable type, and the second attempt does not return the same dataset as the original SQL.  Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

&&  Deleted.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false

Comment: If Default is of type bool?, then it should be
`&& Deleted.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false` or simply  `&& !Deleted.GetValueOrDefault(false)`.

Comment: Thanks...out of interest, if the type had been bool instead of bool?, what would've been the right syntax?

Comment: If the column is Nullable then this would typically be mapped to a nullable type so you wouldn't have bool? unless the column is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

linq;

> `where !(u.Deleted ?? false)`

sql output:

> WHERE (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Deleted] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent1].[Deleted] END) <> cast(1 as bit)