# linq to sql nullable date issue

Tags: c#, .net, date, linq-to-sql

```
int ddlshopID = ddlSupervisorShop.SelectedItem == null ? 0 : ddlSupervisorShop.SelectedValue.ToInt32();
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
List<int> supervisorShopList = shops.Select(a => a.ShopID).ToList<int>();
totalSales = (from ds in db.DailySales
              join p in db.Products on ds.ProductID equals p.ProductID
              where ds.IsActive == true && 
                    p.IsActive == true && 
                    ds.SaleDate.Value.Month == today.Month && 
                    ds.SaleDate.Value.Year == today.Year &&
                    ddlshopID == 0 ? supervisorShopList.Contains(ds.ShopID) : ds.ShopID == ddlshopID
              group ds by new
              {
                  p.ProductCategoryID,
                  p.IsActive,
              }
              into g
              select new TotalPriceDivision
              {
                  TotalPrice = g.Sum(a => a.Quantity * a.PerPrice),
                  DivisionID = g.Key.ProductCategoryID
              }).ToList<TotalPriceDivision>();
```

In this piece of code the line

```
ds.SaleDate.Value.Month == today.Month && ds.SaleDate.Value.Year == today.Year
```

doesn't affect query result. `ds.SaleDate` is nullable date value (not datetime) in the database. Is it because of that? If yes, how can I solve this?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "doesn't affect the query result"?

Comment: Not really, this might be due to failure of some other condition if data is available for current month and year.

Comment: Can you use `GetValueOrDefault` here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4398087/945456

Comment: I mean even if I add or remove that line return result is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what is wrong with this.

surprisingly,incredibly and stupidly

if I order my query as

```
where ds.IsActive == true
&& p.IsActive == true
&& ds.SaleDate.Value.Month == today.Month
&& ds.SaleDate.Value.Year == today.Year
&& ddlshopID == 0 ? supervisorShopList.Contains(ds.ShopID) : ds.ShopID == ddlshopID
```

date conditions doesn't effect query result and it returns wrong.

İf I order it as

```
where ds.IsActive == true
&& p.IsActive == true
&& ddlshopID == 0 ? supervisorShopList.Contains(ds.ShopID) : ds.ShopID == ddlshopID
&& ds.SaleDate.Value.Month == today.Month
&& ds.SaleDate.Value.Year == today.Year
```

it works as I expected

I still can't beleive how is it possible. And if you think there must be another reason please explain me.

Answer (score 1):

```
where ds.IsActive && // don't compare boolean with true
      p.IsActive &&
      ds.SaleDate.HasValue && // add this condition
      ds.SaleDate.Value.Month == today.Month && 
      ds.SaleDate.Value.Year == today.Year &&
      ddlshopID == 0 ? supervisorShopList.Contains(ds.ShopID) : ds.ShopID == ddlshopID
```

Comment: Nice code.. @lazyberezovsky. Instead of checking as null. Check as ds.SalesDate.HasValue which will do the best for you

Comment: @Dhanasekar agree, with nullable it will be better!

Comment: @serhads are you sure? Maybe `IsActive` returns false?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I am quite sure. Because its returns some value. But it returns same value even if all date condition is included or not included to the query. And also I've tried in sql with relevant query.İf I don't put date condition in sql it returns exactly same.if I put date condition in sql returns different.